# "a couple OF times" or "couple times"? "a couple of minutes" or "couple minutes"?

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language

What's the idiomatic way to refer to times and minutes with the adverb couple?

> He did it **a couple of** times.

or

> He already did it **couple times** in past.

The same with minutes:

> I have to go **a couple of** minutes and I'll be back.

or

> I saw him in **couple minutes** ago.

Comment: The phrase is "a couple of times." In conversation (and thus for transcribed speech), people will say "a couple uh times," clipping the *f* from *of*. The "uh" is easy to drop, so it becomes "a couple times," but will be understood to represent the original.

Answer (score 1):

"Couple" can be used as a quantificational noun, in which case, it takes an of-phrase complement (eg. "a couple of minutes"). But it can also be used as an adjective as in "a couple minutes". The adjectival use is informal, if not non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is "**a couple of times**." In conversation (and thus for transcribed speech), people will say "a couple uh times," clipping the letter **f** from of. The "**uh**" is easy to drop, so it becomes "a couple times," but will be understood to represent the original. (user1057190 in comments)

The dictionary states that there are two options in usage: a couple of (formal) and a couple with dropped of (informal).

> **a couple of**, more than two, but not many, of; a small number of; a
>   few: It will take **a couple of days** for the package to get there. A
>   dinner party, whether for a couple of old friends or eight new
>   acquaintances, takes nearly the same amount of effort. Also Informal,
>   a couple (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/couple)